How can we create the triangles in equations of latex?

How can we create the above equations in latex? I don't know how to create the triangles. My current code is as follows, and the triangles don't exist.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\{s : \text{Ship} \mid s.\text{launched} < 1921 \bullet \text{name} == s.\text{name}\}
\]

\end{document}


Where did you get the image from?

Have a look at \llangle and \rrangle from stix2
